# error in application building in angularcli

Tags: angular-cli

```
PS E:\angular new> ng serve -o      
The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
PS E:\angular new> cd project-second
PS E:\angular new\project-second> ng serve -o      
? Port 4200 is already in use.
Would you like to use a different port? No
An unhandled exception occurred: Port 4200 is already in use. Use '--port' to specify a different port.
See "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-ASaxs1\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
PS E:\angular new\project-second> ng serve -o      
? Port 4200 is already in use.
Would you like to use a different port? Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You  need to use different port. And click yes to proceed.